# How to load custom fonts using hook useFonts in Storybook and React Native?

Tags: react-native, expo, storybook

Unfortunately, offical documentation [link](https://storybook.js.org/docs/configure/images-and-assets#referencing-fonts-in-stories) do not say how to load custom fonts using useFonts of Expo Go.

How can I load these fonts?

Answer (score 1):

***To add custom fonts to react-native expo project using useFonts hook***

install expo-font package

copy the custom fonts into assets/fonts folder [see image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E5pqN.png)

In the root directory create an app folder

Within app directory create _layout.ts and add the following code to it. [see image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pvKNp.png)

```
import { useFonts } from "expo-font";
import { Stack } from "expo-router";
import { useCallback } from "react";
import * as SplashScreen from "expo-splash-screen";

SplashScreen.preventAutoHideAsync();

const Layout = () => {
  const [fontsLoaded] = useFonts({
    DMBold: require("../assets/fonts/DMSans-Bold.ttf"),
    DMMedium: require("../assets/fonts/DMSans-Medium.ttf"),
    DMRegular: require("../assets/fonts/DMSans-Regular.ttf"),
  });

const onLayoutRootView = useCallback(async () => {
    if (fontsLoaded) {
      await SplashScreen.hideAsync();
    }
  }, [fontsLoaded]);
  if (!fontsLoaded) return null;

return <Stack onLayout={onLayoutRootView} />
};

export default Layout;
```

[reference blog](https://blog.logrocket.com/adding-custom-fonts-react-native/)

Comment: My problem is not add custom font to RN. My problem is StoryBok load these fonts when I create a story with a component which use this custom font.